# Unable to run docker in Windows WSL2

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to run Docker in WSL2 on Windows 10. I first force updated Windows 10 to v2004 (OS Build 19041.508). Earlier, I had Ubuntu 20.04 running on WSL, it seem to use WSL1:

[image]

Thats why, I guess, docker is not listing Ubuntu in its `Resources/WSL integration` window:

[image]

So, I tried `wsl --set-version` as suggested [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetUpDockerWithinWindowsSystemForLinuxWSL2OnWindows10.aspx). But got error "The operation timed out because the response was not received from the virtual machine or container":

[image]

So as suggested [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/740#issuecomment-644842771), I tried to unregister and re-register my Ubuntu after setting my default WSL:

[image]

It seems that `wsl --unregister` deletes distro files too (which is not really intuitive from the command name "unregister"). Is it so? Are all my older distro files gone? If not, how can I get them back? Also when I tried to reinstall Ubuntu from Windows Store, it detected that Ubuntu is still installed on my machine , but trying to launch it gave me same error:

[image]

How do I fix this?

**Update**

I also tried by downloading and renaming `Ubuntu_2004.2020.424.0_x64.appx` to `Ubuntu_2004.2020.424.0_x64.tar` and then running `wsl --import`. But got same error. Also I extracted this tar and manually ran `ubuntu2004.exe` as suggested [here](https://damsteen.nl/blog/2018/08/29/installing-wsl-manually-on-non-system-drive). But still the same error.

Comment: Have you installed the updated WSL kernel required for WSL2?  Do you have the required optional Windows features installed?  “Is it so?” - [It is clear based on the description of the command.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#unregister-and-reinstall-a-distribution)

Comment: Yes; The files were deleted when you issued that command

Comment: @Ramhound sorry I forgot to mention, I installed updated WSL kernel. Also I tried several ways to delete old unregistered Ubuntu completely as suggested [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-legacy) and by right clicking on Ubuntu tile in Windows start and then clicking Uninstall. Now I am able to proceed.

Comment: You should submit a detailed answered in that case.

Comment: Actually I just did what I said in those three lines. I dont know if its worth a dedicated answer. Also want to know if you are aware how can I connect vscode to running docker container?